# Selenium 'Options' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I open a website, upwork.com, to do some webscraping but trying to click an element is throwing an error.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options: Options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options. add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get ("https://www.upwork.com/nx/jobs/search/?from_recent_search=true&q=webscraping&sort=recency")
options.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="job-1645717982262001664"]/div[1]/div/h3/a').click()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yatharthmahajan/Documents/Python/pythonProject/webscraper.py", line 8, in <module>
    options.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="job-1645717982262001664"]/div[1]/div/h3/a').click()
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `find_element` method on the `options` object, which is not correct. You should use the `find_element` method on the driver object like below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.upwork.com/nx/jobs/search/?from_recent_search=true&q=webscraping&sort=recency")
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="job-1645717982262001664"]/div[1]/div/h3/a')
link.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="job-1645717982262001664"]/div[1]/div/h3/a').click()
```

Not:

```
options.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="job-1645717982262001664"]/div[1]/div/h3/a').click()
```